# C# sort Arraylist strings alphabetical and on length

Tags: c#, string, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList` of `String`.

Given:

```
{A,C,AA,B,CC,BB}
```

`Arraylist.Sort` gives:

```
{A,AA,B,BB,C,CC}
```

What I need is:

```
{A,B,C,AA,BB,CC}
```

Comment: First split the list in seperat list depending on length and then sort them individually.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a strongly typed `List<string>`?

Comment: There are speed advantages of using an ArrayList over a LinkedList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of old school but, I went the IComparer Interface . . .

```
public class SortAlphabetLength : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    public int Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        if (x.ToString().Length == y.ToString().Length)
            return string.Compare(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
        else if (x.ToString().Length > y.ToString().Length)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

and then test it . . .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList()
        {
            "A","AA","B","BB","C","CC"
        };

        SortAlphabetLength alphaLen = new SortAlphabetLength();
        values.Sort(alphaLen);

        foreach (string itm in values)
            Console.WriteLine(itm);
    }
}
```

output:

```
A
B
C
AA
BB
CC
```

Comment: Now put a `null` value in that collection and see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see that in the question.  I'm just trying to answer the question.  Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: If you're writing code to only display the sorted values of that one example than you may as well just print out A, B C, ...  It's *example* input, not the only input he'll ever have to put into it.

Comment: Thanks for nitpicking. Wise, Sir.

Comment: Yeah, robust code that works is overrated; it's much better to use code that's longer, more complex, is harder to understand, and occasionally crashes when there is a sensible course of action.

Comment: I never said that you did.  Look, I don't want to get into an argument with you.  All I'm doing is suggesting an answer.  I did not include the null case, but thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Servy The `null` case in this piece of code is really up to the user since we have to decide whether to collect the `null`s either at the very top of the list or at the very bottom of the list. Also, it is probably BEST to write unit tests to test the logic since there can be a small combination of ways for the `null`s to arise. This is why I did not bother to do the `null` cases. Also, I'm doing a bit of proof-of-concept not trying to write an entire application and code defensively for every single possible case.

Answer (score 12):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList {"A","C","AA","B","CC","BB"};

var sorted = list.Cast<string>()
                 .OrderBy(str => str.Length)
                 .ThenBy(str => str);

//LinqPad specific print call
sorted.Dump();
```

prints:

```
A 
B 
C 
AA 
BB 
CC
```

Comment: Just note that this doesn't modify the ArrayList, it creates a new sequence of the values from that collection.  (It may be acceptable, it's just important to be aware of that.)

Comment: yes, sure, good note. Another note that even if you modify `list` after `sorted` variable has been declared, but before actually called - than it would contain new element. `sorted` query is being executed in deferred manner

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to do this with Linq as so:

```
string [] list = { "A","C","AA","B","CC","BB"};

var sorted = list.OrderBy(x=>x.Length).ThenBy(x=>x);
```

Note that the `OrderBy` method returns a new list. If you want to modify the original, then you need to re-assign it as so:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x=>x.Length).ThenBy(x=>x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `ToArray()` method (or just using a `List<string>` instad of an ArrayList) to take advantage of the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` functions. It would look something like this:

```
list = list.OrderBy(/*Order it by length*/).ThenBy(/*Order alphabetically*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `IComparable` class taking in two Strings and sort them as follows:

```
if (a.Length == b.Length)
    return String.Compare(a, b);
return a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length);
```

You may also want to handle `null` cases.